# LiveReload ASP.net MVC web app with Grunt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Is it possible in grunt to watch files and automatically reload a ASP.net MVC web application. Or does livereload only work with files served through grunt. I have come across grunt plugin 'grunt-iisexpress' but not really sure if I can use it, in conjunction with tasks to reload a ASP.net MVC webapp when a file has changed.

I do not have any index.html as a starting page in my web app but _ViewStart.cshtml which kicks off the whole application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible.  I just got live-reloading in my ASP.NET app using **grunt-contrib-watch** (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch).  It only took a few minutes.

I used this article as a guide:
http://www.aliirz.com/javascript/2013/12/25/Live-Reload-with-Grunt/.

Do this via a command prompt in the ASP.NET app's folder.

### 1. Install grunt-contrib-watch

If you don't yet have a package.json file and want to save your dependencies in one:

```
npm init
```

Then add Grunt and grunt-contrib-watch to your project:

```
npm install --save-dev  grunt grunt-contrib-watch
```

### 2.  Configure Grunt

Next create a `Gruntfile.js` in that same folder.  Here's mine:

```
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.initConfig({
      watch: {
        views: {
          files: [
              'Views/**/*.cshtml', 
              'Scripts/**/*.js',
              'Content/**/*.css',
              'Content/images/**/*',            
              'bin/**/*.dll'
          ],
          options: {
            livereload: true,
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

### 3. Run live reload server

Run your live-reload server alongside your ASP.NET app:

```
grunt watch
```

### 4. Add Snippet to ASP.NET

Finally, to enable it in your ASP.NET app, simply add the live-reload snippet to your Layouts and/or Views:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on here? I want to try and set this up but being fairly unfamiliar with LiveReload and Node I'm not sure how to follow these instructions. When I tried it looked like I was creating a branch of a GIT repository or similar?

Comment: @Winston i don't understand where http://localhost:35729/livereload.js 
comes from ? 
do i need to take it from grunt-contrib-watch under my node-modules ?

Comment: @eranotzap 35729 is a default port where livereload server runs.  If you want to specify any other port you should specify port number in options e.g. options: { livereload: 4455}  this will start livereload server on port 4455 and you need to include <script src="http://localhost:4455/livereload.js"></script> in Layouts.cshtml file.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this generator for mvc : https://github.com/has606/generator-aspnetmvc Perhaps you could do something like the grunt file in the project :

```
livereload: {
    options: {livereload: 32684},
    files: [
      '<%%= yeoman.app %>/Content/**/*.css',
      '<%%= yeoman.app %>/Scripts/**/*',
      '<%%= yeoman.app %>/Content/images/**/*',
      '<%%= yeoman.app %>/Views/**/*.cshtml',
      '<%%= yeoman.app %>/bin/**/*.dll'
    ]
  }
```

So any changes to views or compilation, reloads the site

Comment: That looks like it could almost work. I will give this a try tomorrow thanks.